# previous values get overwritten list

Tags: c#, datalist, cart

i am trying to add items to cart which are stored in session but the session values are overwritten when i add a new product to the cart.

```
private List<int> newCart = new List<int>();
    protected void dlstCartItems_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
        {
            var arg = e.CommandArgument;
            DropDownList ddlList = e.Item.FindControl("ddlAvailableSizes"+e.CommandArgument) as DropDownList;
            int currentItemID = int.Parse(this.dlstCartItems.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString());
            if (ddlList.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please Select Size');", true);
            }
            else
            {

                newCart.Add(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                Session["Cart"] = newCart;
                if (Session["Cart"] != null)
                {

                    int ct = ((List<int>)Session["Cart"]).Count;
                    lblCartMessage.Text = Convert.ToString(ct)+" "+"Product";

                }


            }



        }
    }
```

my problem is when ever i add a new product the old product is no more there in the list and the product count is always 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list in which u are adding should be defined at a class level. Whenever you are adding new product , private List newCart = new List(); should not be executed otherwise it will make the count zero after addition you would only be left with the latest addition.

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the cart by `Session["Cart"] = newCart;`.
In order to do this write:

```
 newCart = Session["Cart"] as List<int>;
 if (newCart == null)
 {
    newCart = new List<int>();
    Session["Cart"] = newCart;
 }

// Rest of the code adding to newCart etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps newcart is always empty on the execution of dlstCartItems_ItemCommand and therefore

```
Session["Cart"] = newCart;
```

clears values

Answer (score -1):

protected void dlstCartItems_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        List newCart;

```
    if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
    {
        var arg = e.CommandArgument;
        DropDownList ddlList = e.Item.FindControl("ddlAvailableSizes" + e.CommandArgument) as DropDownList;
        int currentItemID = int.Parse(this.dlstCartItems.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString());
        if (ddlList.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please Select Size');", true);
        }
        else
        {

            if (Session["Cart"] == null)
            {
                newCart = new List<int>();
                newCart.Add(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                Session["Cart"] = newCart;
            }
            else
            {
                newCart = Session["Cart"] as List<int>;
                newCart.Add(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                Session["Cart"] = newCart;
            }





            int ct = ((List<int>)Session["Cart"]).Count;
            lblCartMessage.Text = Convert.ToString(ct) + " " + "Product";




        }



    }
}
```